# Gratis MySql optimizer

Tags: windows, gratis, mysql, performance-analysis, optimization

I have gotten by until now with ensuing 3rd order norm and having good indexes & foreign keys.

Today an AJAX query is exceeding 30 seconds on a modest search (PHP builds JSON arrays for each candidate who has multiple jobs which have multiple skills, with approx. 1.5k candidates with average 5 jobs with average 5 skills & not a lot of other data (start/end date, company name & address).

I started using `microtome()` in PH and each query is taking about 0.075 seconds. Sure, there are a lot of queries (max 1,500 x 5 x 5?), and the database ***will*** grow, but 0.075 seconds seems long to me, for  a query with no `JOIN`s.

I am currently using Kachegrind to profile my PHP code, but perhaps I ought to be looking at my SQL?

I am looking for a gratis tool, for Widows, which will :

- Analyse my table structure, and offer optimizations (e.g indices/foreign keys/data types)
- Analyse my data, in addition to the bare structure, if anything can be gleaned from that
- Monitor query performance at run time & offer suggestions for improvements

I haven't really looked into this before, so can’t give much detail on what I am after, alas. I envisage a tool where I click a button and it gives me the low hanging fruit of optimization, at least the 80% of the 80/20 rule. I realize that manual optimization is likely to be better, but I don’t have time to get really up to speed at guru level, so can accept a tool that gives my performance a boost. E.g stuff like [this](https://theemon.com/ultimate-guide-mysql-query-optimization/)

Or, should I be asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/  ?

Comment: For starters, at least MariaDB ships with `mysqldumpslow` (listing up the "slowest queries" which are usually those with the most potential for optimization – missing indexes and such). I vaguely remember having used some other tool in the past that spit out "quick best candidates", but unfortunately cannot remember (or find) it now…

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "table_name" PROCEDURE ANALYSE ( )`for static analysis of structure, or `ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;` or `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable` ? Aha, do you mean [mysqlisnchk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-check.html) ?

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/17/5/speed-your-mysql-queries-300-times explains how to check for slow queries in MySql and MySql also has [mysqldumpslow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html) - I really ought to switch to MaraiDB

Comment: I will be posting useful links here as I research. If no one else answers, I will try to add a answer to help others in future. Let's start with [6 Best SQL Query Optimization Tools and Software](https://www.addictivetips.com/net-admin/sql-query-optimization-tools/) [SentryOne's Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) is looking good

Comment: https://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/database-performance-analyzer-free

Comment: Looong list of [free SQL tools](https://www.sqlshack.com/free-sql-tools/)